# Windows bat alternative for Bash inline command

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, cmd

Is there any Windows equivalent syntax to run a command within another command in a bat script file?

In Linux, you can simply use [$(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663595/bash-for-inline-command) or ``.

Comment: Windows .bat files are a historical throwback, why not install Perl instead?

Comment: Batch files still have a place - eg if you have to run one as part of an installation script. You can't assume Perl will be installed on the user's system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, at least for simple things:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f %%w in ('echo xyzzy') do set var=%%w
echo Output is %var%
endlocal
```

The output of that script is:

```
Output is xyzzy
```

with the `xyzzy` coming from the `echo` command.

Running `for /?` from a command window should give you a more comprehensive list of options.

Comment: I think this is handled by 'for-in' construct not internally by Windows commandline engine. It doesn't seem to work in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828801/imagmagick-how-to-add-a-gradient-splice-to-an-image-using-one-convert-command/11864792#11864792

Comment: @Moshen, `for` is the only way I think you can do this. Even `bash` isn't running the code with `$()`, it's simply substituting the standard output from another process. That's no different to storing it in an environment variable and then using that variable, as in my answer.

Comment: @Mohsen - FOR is an internal command, so it most definitely is being handled by the commandline engine.

Comment: `FOR` appeared in MS-DOS v2.0 - here's the [XP documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I don't have a Windows test system around at the moment -- but don't you need to add the `"usebackq"` parameter, and then also use backquotes ``` to surround the `echo xyzzy` command? *for /f "usebackq delims= " %%w in ( \`echo xyz\` ) do set var=%%w*

Comment: @Kurt, no, not really necessary. `usebackq` changes what each type of quote does (execute command, read file, use literal text and so on). `usebackq` with backquotes is the same as single quotes without that option, as per `for /?` descriptive text.