# Jenkins Windows Batch Command Inject environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I try to inject environment variable into Jenkins and use it on Editable Email Notification in order to send *git commit* information to others.

```
echo GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git show -s --format=%cn) > propsfile
echo GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git show -s --format=%ce) >> propsfile
echo GIT_COMMIT=$(git show -s --format=%h) >> propsfile
echo GIT_MESSAGE=$(git show -s --format=%B) >> propsfile
```

Mac and Ubuntu Slave works fine with upper code, but windows just **echo** inside command.

For Example,

```
echo GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git show -s --format=%cn)
```

returns

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git show -s --format=%cn)
```

What I intend is

```
echo GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=Committer Name
```

How to execute a command inside a command in **Windows**?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929493/windows-bat-alternative-for-bash-inline-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using Git Bash.

I add Git Bash's Path into System Enviroment Path.
Therefore, I can use bash command directly from PowerShell.